# Raspberry para sistema de monitoramento

Tags: raspberry-pi, câmera

pessoal.

Gostaria de fazer um sistema de segurança com câmeras que monitorariam um ambiente e reconhecessem caso aparecesse alguma coisa fora do comum.

Na verdade gostaria de usar aprendizado de máquina para que, mostrando alguns riscos, ele consiga distinguir um cenário normal do mesmo cenário com um risco.

Pensei em usar a Raspberry Pi com uma câmera que tiraria as fotos e compararia, mas tem muitas coisas que eu não sei sobre a Raspberry:

-Ela só tira várias fotos de tempos em tempos ou também consegue comparar vídeos ao vivo com as imagens aprendidas?

-É possível deixar rodando um software com IA(pra fazer a comparação das imagens) numa Raspberry, isso é, ela não é frágil demais para um serviço tão pesado?

-Posso programar isso usando Python e Prolog ou a raspberry tem alguma linguagem pré definida?

Alguém já fez alguma coisa parecida, consegue me dar informações pra fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em linhas gerais, é possível. Só depende de como você vai descrever e identificar o que é algo fora do comum...
Mas coisas como identificar que existem pessoas é bem simples. Pesquise sobre openCV.

> -Ela só tira várias fotos de tempos em tempos ou também consegue comparar vídeos ao vivo com as imagens aprendidas?

Sim, é possível "comparar imagens"

> -É possível deixar rodando um software com IA(pra fazer a comparação das imagens) numa Raspberry, isso é, ela não é frágil demais para um serviço tão pesado?

Na questão física, ela é bem frágil. Não deixar em ambientes abertos. Mas ela dá conta de fazer algum processamento de imagem e rodar redes neurais.

> -Posso programar isso usando Python e Prolog ou a raspberry tem alguma linguagem pré definida?

Não tem linguagem definida. É um computador linux...

Comment: Obrigada por responder a todas as perguntas, foi muito útil. Fico feliz que ela aguente redes neurais, era uma preocupação.

Answer (score 1):

O raspberry é na verdade um computador normal que vem instalada uma versão do linux, logo vc pode usar qualquer linguagem que seja possível compilar nesse sistema operacional. Sobre os padrões de reconhecimento de imagem, [o google tem uma api bem bacana para esse fim](https://cloud.google.com/vision/pricing?hl=pt-br). Olhando no internet vi esse [tutorial](https://www.filipeflop.com/blog/modulo-camera-raspberry-pi/) bem bacana sobre trabalhar com cameras no raspberry.

Answer (score 1):

Olá o raspberry é um computador, então basta você criar um programa com a sua finalidade desejada. Existe uma biblioteca chamada OpenCV, existe para várias linguagens... Recomendo python pelo fato de que o phython contem várias bibliotecas para raspberry.
Links:
https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html
 - https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/
 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bdnBfu0-aEA
 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=88HdqNDQsEk